# Should British r be spoken out in liaison?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, rhoticity, received-pronunciation

For example, the r in "better" is not pronounced in British English. How about the "r" in "a better idea"?

Comment: You mean in Southern English, or RP, or something. Northern English, Scottish, and the English of Northern Ireland don't do what you're talking about because they're all rhotic. Please do not use *British* to mean RP.

Comment: Let's say, RP. What is "all rhotic", any example?

Comment: Rhotic speakers say the *r* of *better* no matter what comes after it. Non-rhotic speakers only say it in liaison as you might put it.

Comment: OK. So rhotic speakers are all RP? What's the definition for rhotic?

Comment: Maybe not even the t ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-glottalization

Comment: Janus, you're right.  I've deleted my answer, and added it here as a comment ... @tchrist, I disagree. There's more non-rhotic than rhotic in Northern England: in fact, I can only think of parts of Lancashire (such as Wigan) where rhoticity is usual. What must strike outsiders as odd is the way that non-rhotic English-speakers treat any word ending with schwa as if it's spelt -er. Hence 'India and China' pronounced 'Indier and China" and 'Anna Atkins' pronounced 'Anner Atkins / Anna Ratkins'. It sounds slovenly to me, but linguists will say that usage rules!

Comment: @congliu The definition of a rhotic dialect is one where final /r/ is always pronounced. The definition of a non-rhotic dialect is one where syllable-final /r/ is not pronounced before a consonant or a pause. A common feature in non-rhotic (and even some rhotic) dialects is the intrusive r, whereby syllables that end in a vowel get an /r/ added to them before a vowel, as David mentions.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good of you to mention that some rhotic speakers have intrusive-r as well. I don’t rightly understand it, but it really does happen. Examples I know of are from speakers raised in rhotic areas ***that border*** non-rhotic areas in North America, but I don’t know that that’s why. Something that I think different from this is how certain idiolects feature an intrusive-r only in specific words and derived terms: the well-known but perhaps not well-explained example of *wash, washed, washing, Washington* comes to mind, perhaps especially in older (but still educated) speakers.

Comment: Isn't a simpler definition [covering internal and final r's]  that non-rhotic speakers only pronounce 'r' *immediately before a vowel*?  So a rhotic speaker sounds all the r's in 'turn', 'pepper and salt' *and* 'salt and pepper', while a non-rhotic speaker *only* sounds the 'r' in 'pepper and salt'.

Comment: @DavidGarner You’re right, that is a simpler way of putting it. To err on the side of caution, it would be best to make it “before a vowel _sound_”, since (orthographic) vowels like the one in _-ed_ don’t cause the /r/ to be pronounced.

Comment: Of course, Janus, I should've specified *sound*.

Comment: Despite 18th c French language nazis, writing isn't language. 'Before a vowel' should mean by default 'before a pronounced vowel' (but I realize people only see what is written)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rhotic English is a term to describes varieties of English in which orthographic 'r' is usually pronounced, even at the end of a syllable. In non-rhotic varieties of English - such as Southern Standard British English - orthographic 'r' is only pronounced if followed by a vowel. It doesn't matter if there is a double /r/ or not in the orthography:

- car / ka:
- car park / ka: pa:k
- car alarm /ka:r əla:m
- carrot / kærət

Of course, whether this is actually a form of liaison or not depends on your theoretical phonological background. In order to be liaison, one would have to believe that there is some kind of underlying /r/ in the words where we don't pronounce it. This may or may not be true.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Presumably, it must be true that there is an underlying /r/ to those who do not have intrusive r’s in their speech. Otherwise, I can see no way of explaining minimal pairs like _whoring_ vs. _(humming and) hawing_, etc. Claiming that there is no underlying /r/ only really works, as far as I can work out, with speakers who do have intrusive r’s.